# Armazenar List<Menu> Na memória ou em Cookie

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, asp.net-mvc-5

boa tarde.

Tenho uma aplicação que possui todo um nível de gerenciamento de permissões de acessos a páginas e uma série de outras configurações.

Sempre quando um usuário se autentica, eu monto uma lista com todos os menus (links/páginas) que este usuário pode acessar no sistema. O que acontece é que neste momento (homologação da versão mais recente) a lista está sendo populada a cada requisição/refresh de uma página. O que eu quero é saber se tem alguma forma de armazenar isso em algo que eu possa consultar sempre que precisar, sem a necessidade de ir no banco de dados.

Até o momento eu já utilizei (tentativas):

1. Session: funciona, mas não gosto de usar, ainda mais que a aplicação possui um volume diário de +10k pessoas;
2. UserData do FormsAuthentication: Tentei converter uma viewModel para JavaScriptSerialization, mas como o tamanho ficou enorme, o mesmo acabou não sendo criado e não gerado o cookie;
3. OutputCache da ActionResult: Esse método foi um dos que mais gostei, porém ele não é específico para cada sessão/login e sim para a aplicação como um todo;

Espero que possam me ajudar, porque a um bom tempo venho quebrando muito a cabeça para pensar nesta solução.

Abraços!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Há, ainda, a solução do Stack Overflow: [Redis](http://redis.io/).

O Redis [pode ser instalado no Windows](https://msopentech.com/opentech-projects/redis/).

[O time do Stack Overflow escreveu um excelente módulo de integração do Redis à sua aplicação ASP.NET MVC](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis).

[A serialização JSON fica por conta deste outro pacote](https://github.com/imperugo/StackExchange.Redis.Extensions).

Se precisar de ajuda com estes componentes, só fazer outras perguntas.

Comment: Entendi. Não tinha conhecimento sobre o Redis ainda. Mas com relação aos 3 itens que eu citei acima, apenas a Session funcionou, mas ninguém recomenda o uso dela, então estou praticamente sem nenhuma solução ainda...

Comment: Por isso mesmo. O Redis funciona como um mecanismo de sessão, cujas chaves são expiráveis. Você instancia um valor tendo como chave alguma identificação do usuário e expira este valor depois de um determinado tempo. Sendo o Redis um grande dicionário (chave-valor), você pode colocar qualquer coisa no valor, incluindo HTML e JSON, se assim desejar.

Comment: então eu posso fazer um "Redis["teste"].Value = listMenu (List<Menu>)"? E ele também expira igual uma session?

Comment: Pode. Sim, expira igual Session. Você pode expirar manualmente, se quiser.

Comment: me desculpa a pergunta, mas o que eu ganho usando o Redis ao invés da Session?

Comment: Fica isolado do mecanismo de Session normal, que tem um problema clássico de balanceamento; Tão simples de usar quanto a Session normal; Você pode usar Redis como uma cache de qualquer coisa, e não apenas de Sessions, mas também de dados que não mudam muito.